# Combo Matching in a digital implementation of Reiner Knizia's 'Schotten Totten'

Tags: python, playing-cards

I'm implementing Reiner Knizia's card game 'Schotten Totten' in Python. It's a card game for two players, where you compete to claim boundary stones between you and your opponent by forming poker-like combinations of three cards on each side of the stone.

My goal is to make the implementation easily moddable, so that users can implement their own rule variations (for example, change the  distribution of the cards, the amount of boundary stones, the amount of cards required to complete a combo, etc.) and that the user can also add their own combo types to the game.

I'm in the process of implementing the combo matching code. In the original game, there are five combo types, in order of rank:

- Equal color and consecutive values
- Equal values
- Equal color
- Consecutive values
- Anything else

A higher ranked combination always beats a lower ranked combinaton, regardless of card value. When two sets of cards have the same rank, then the highest combined card value wins.

There are two relevant questions for any set of cards that my code is trying to answer:

- if the set is complete, what's the best matching combo?
- if the set is incomplete, what's the best possible completion based on the cards that aren't in play yet? (Players may claim a stone early if their complete combo beats out any possible completion of an opponent's incomplete set of cards).

I'm wondering if my code is readable, easily extensible, and if the structure makes sense. Any other feedback is also welcome.

```
#card.py

from dataclasses import dataclass, field


def _card_id_generator():
    """
    This generator function yields a unique card ID each time it's invoked. This is to ensure that the distinct
    identity of each card is maintained in set operations when there are multiple copies of the same card in
    a user-defined game variant.
    """
    card_id = 0
    while True:
        yield card_id
        card_id += 1


_card_ids = _card_id_generator()


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Card:
    """
    Represents a playing card with a color, value, and unique ID.
    """
    color: str
    value: int
    id: int = field(default_factory=lambda: next(_card_ids))

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.value < other.value

    def __add__(self, other):
        return self.value + other.value

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Card(color={self.color!r}, value={self.value})'
```

```
#available_combos.py

from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import Iterator, Sequence
from itertools import chain
from typing import Protocol
from card import Card


class Combo(Protocol):
    name: str
    rank: int
    n_cards_complete_combo: int

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        ...

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        ...


class HelperStepSize:
    """
    A helper class to handle operations related to the step size in a combo.

    Args:
        n_cards_complete_combo (int): The number of cards required to complete the combo. Must be larger than 0.
        step_size (int): The required step size of the values of the cards that make up the combo. Must be larger than 0.
    """
    def __init__(self, n_cards_complete_combo: int, step_size: int):
        self._n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._step_size = step_size

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the given cards match the combo criteria. 'cards' may be an empty Sequence.
        """
        return len(cards) == self._n_cards_complete_combo and self._cards_have_correct_step_size(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards using the available cards. Both 'cards_to_complete' and
        'available_cards' may be an empty Sequence. If no valid completion is found, returns an empty list.
        """
        card_samples = self._select_one_card_per_value(cards_to_complete, available_cards)
        highest_value, lowest_value = max(card_samples.keys(), default=0), min(card_samples.keys(), default=0)

        for values_to_test in self._generate_values_to_test(highest_value, lowest_value):
            cards_to_test = self._select_cards_to_test(card_samples, values_to_test)
            if self._are_cards_to_test_valid(cards_to_test, cards_to_complete):
                return cards_to_test
        return []

    def _cards_have_correct_step_size(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the sorted values of 'cards' all have a step size that equals 'self._step_size'.
        """
        cards = sorted(cards)
        for i in range(1, len(cards)):
            if cards[i].value - cards[i - 1].value != self._step_size:
                return False
        return True

    @staticmethod
    def _select_one_card_per_value(cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> dict[int, Card]:
        """
        Selects one card per value from the given 'cards_to_complete' and 'available_cards'. Gives priority to
        cards from 'cards_to_complete' if both 'cards_to_complete' and 'available_cards' contain a valid sample.
        """
        card_samples = {card.value: card for card in available_cards}
        card_samples.update({card.value: card for card in cards_to_complete})
        return card_samples

    def _generate_values_to_test(self, highest_value: int, lowest_value: int) -> Iterator[list[int]]:
        """
        Returns sequences of values in descending order, each containing 'self._n_cards_complete_combo' values, and
        all values having a step size equal to 'self._step_size'. The highest possible value of a sequence is
        'highest_value', and the lowest possible value is 'lowest_value'.

        For example, when highest_value=8, lowest_value=2, self._step_size=2 and self._n_cards_complete_combo=3,
        this will yield: [8, 6, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 4, 2].
        """
        min_value_spread = self._step_size * (self._n_cards_complete_combo - 1)
        while highest_value - lowest_value >= min_value_spread:
            valid_range = range(highest_value, lowest_value - 1, -self._step_size)
            yield list(valid_range[:self._n_cards_complete_combo])
            highest_value -= 1
    
    @staticmethod
    def _select_cards_to_test(card_samples: dict[int, Card], values_to_test: list[int]) -> list[Card]:
        """
        Selects cards from the 'card_samples' dictionary based on the values in 'values_to_test'.
        """
        cards_to_test = []
        for value in values_to_test:
            if card := card_samples.get(value):
                cards_to_test.append(card)
        return cards_to_test

    def _are_cards_to_test_valid(self, cards_to_test: list[Card], cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the selected cards to test are valid: all cards in 'cards_to_complete' must appear in 'cards_to_test',
        and 'cards_to_test' must pass the criteria of 'self.is_match'.
        """
        return all(card in cards_to_test for card in cards_to_complete) and self.is_match(cards_to_test)


class HelperEqualAttribute:
    """
    A helper class to handle operations related to equal attributes in a combo.

    Args:
        n_cards_complete_combo (int): The number of cards required to complete the combo. Must be larger than 0.
        attr_to_test (str): The attribute of the card that needs to be equal for all cards in the combo.
            Supported attributes: 'value' or 'color'.
    """
    def __init__(self, n_cards_complete_combo: int, attr_to_test: str):
        self._n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._attr_to_test = attr_to_test

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]):
        """
        Checks if the given cards match the combo criteria. 'cards' may be an empty Sequence.
        """
        return len(cards) == self._n_cards_complete_combo and self._cards_have_eq_attr(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards using the available cards. Both 'cards_to_complete' and
        'available_cards' may be an empty Sequence. If no valid completion is found, returns an empty list.
        """
        completions = []
        for cards_to_test in self._prepare_cards_to_test(cards_to_complete, available_cards):
            if self._are_cards_to_test_valid(cards_to_test, cards_to_complete):
                completions.append(cards_to_test)
        return max(completions, default=[])

    def _eq_attr(self, card: Card):
        """Shorthand for 'getattr(card, self._attr_to_test)'."""
        return getattr(card, self._attr_to_test)

    def _cards_have_eq_attr(self, cards: Sequence[Card]):
        """Checks if 'self._attr_to_test' matches for all cards."""
        return len({self._eq_attr(card) for card in cards}) == 1

    def _prepare_cards_to_test(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence) -> Iterator[list[Card]]:
        """Organizes cards for testing, grouping them by attribute value.

        - If the number of cards required to complete the combo is less than or equal to `self._n_cards_complete_combo`,
          all cards from `cards_to_complete` are included.
        - If additional cards are needed to meet `self._n_cards_complete_combo`, the method adds the highest-valued
          cards from `available_cards`.
        """
        ac_by_value = sorted(available_cards, reverse=True)
        cards_by_attr = defaultdict(list)

        for card in chain(cards_to_complete, ac_by_value):
            if len(cards_by_attr[self._eq_attr(card)]) < self._n_cards_complete_combo:
                cards_by_attr[self._eq_attr(card)].append(card)

        for cards_to_test in cards_by_attr.values():
            yield cards_to_test

    def _are_cards_to_test_valid(self, cards_to_test: Sequence[Card], cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card]):
        """
        Checks if the selected cards to test are valid: all cards in 'cards_to_complete' must appear in 'cards_to_test',
        and 'cards_to_test' must pass the criteria in 'self.is_match'.
        """
        return all(card in cards_to_test for card in cards_to_complete) and self.is_match(cards_to_test)


class ComboAnyCards:
    """
    All cards allowed.
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        if len(cards) == self.n_cards_complete_combo:
            return True

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        cards_to_add = self._select_highest_cards_to_add(cards_to_complete, available_cards)
        cards_to_test = [*cards_to_complete, *cards_to_add]
        return cards_to_test if self.is_match(cards_to_test) else []

    def _select_highest_cards_to_add(self, cards_to_complete, available_cards):
        n_cards_to_add = self.n_cards_complete_combo - len(cards_to_complete)
        return sorted(available_cards, reverse=True)[:n_cards_to_add]

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, rank={self.rank}, n_cards_complete_combo={self.n_cards_complete_combo})'


class ComboStepSizeOne:
    """
    Cards must have consecutive values.
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_step_size = HelperStepSize(self.n_cards_complete_combo, step_size=1)

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_step_size.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        return self._helper_step_size.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, rank={self.rank}, n_cards_complete_combo={self.n_cards_complete_combo})'


class ComboEqualColors:
    """
    Cards must have equal colors.
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_colors = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, attr_to_test='color')

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, rank={self.rank}, n_cards_complete_combo={self.n_cards_complete_combo})'


class ComboEqualValues:
    """
    Cards must have equal values.
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo: int = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_colors = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, attr_to_test='value')

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, rank={self.rank}, n_cards_complete_combo={self.n_cards_complete_combo})'


class ComboEqualColorsStepSizeOne:
    """
    Cards must have both equal colors and consecutive values.
    """
    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int):
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_colors = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, attr_to_test='color')
        self._helper_step_size = HelperStepSize(self.n_cards_complete_combo, step_size=1)

    def is_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.is_match(cards) and self._helper_step_size.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> list[Card]:
        completions = []

        for available_cards_to_test in self._prepare_available_cards_to_test(available_cards):
            completion = self._helper_step_size.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards_to_test)
            if self.is_match(completion):
                completions.append(completion)
        return max(completions, default=[])

    @staticmethod
    def _prepare_available_cards_to_test(available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> Iterator[list[Card]]:
        """
        Prepares available cards for testing by grouping them by color.
        """
        cards_by_color = defaultdict(list)
        for card in available_cards:
            cards_by_color[card.color].append(card)

        for available_cards_to_test in cards_by_color.values():
            yield available_cards_to_test

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}(name={self.name!r}, rank={self.rank}, n_cards_complete_combo={self.n_cards_complete_combo})'
```

```
#active_combos.py

from collections.abc import Iterable, Sequence
from available_combos import Combo
from card import Card


class ActiveCombos:
    def __init__(self, active_combos: Iterable[Combo]):
        self.active_combos: list[Combo] = sorted(active_combos, key=lambda combo: combo.rank)

    def best_match(self, cards: Sequence[Card]) -> Combo | None:
        """
        Matches 'cards' with the best possible combo type in 'active_combos'.
        """
        for combo in self.active_combos:
            if combo.is_match(cards):
                return combo

    def best_completion(self, cards_to_complete: Sequence[Card], available_cards: Sequence[Card]) -> tuple[Combo, list[Card]] | None:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards to complete a combo among the active combos.
        """
        for combo in self.active_combos:
            if completion := combo.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards):
                return combo, completion
```

```
#settings.py

from collections.abc import Iterable
from dataclasses import dataclass
from available_combos import Combo, ComboAnyCards, ComboStepSizeOne, ComboEqualColors, ComboEqualValues, ComboEqualColorsStepSizeOne


@dataclass
class GameSettings:
    card_colors: Iterable[str]
    card_values: Iterable[int]
    hand_size: int
    n_targets: int
    target_name: str
    max_n_cards_complete_combo: int
    active_combos: Iterable[Combo]


schotten_totten_settings = GameSettings(
    card_colors=('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown', 'purple'),
    card_values=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9),
    hand_size=6,
    n_targets=9,
    target_name='stone',
    max_n_cards_complete_combo=3,
    active_combos=(
        ComboEqualColorsStepSizeOne(name='COLOR-RUN', rank=1, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboEqualValues(name='THREE OF A KIND', rank=2, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboEqualColors(name='COLOR', rank=3, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboStepSizeOne(name='RUN', rank=4, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboAnyCards(name='SUM', rank=5, n_cards_complete_combo=3)
    )
)

# User can add custom settings if they wish.
```

```
# main.py

# Intended to show functionality of the combo matching.

from card import Card
from active_combos import ActiveCombos
from settings import schotten_totten_settings

s = schotten_totten_settings
combos = ActiveCombos(s.active_combos)

cards_to_test = [
    [Card('blue', 1), Card('blue', 3), Card('blue', 2)], 
    [Card('blue', 3), Card('red', 2)], 
    [Card('green', 5)], 
    []
]

available_cards = [Card('green', 4), Card('blue', 5), Card('red', 5), Card('green', 3)]

for cards in cards_to_test:
    print(f'Cards to test: {cards}')
    print(f'Match: {combos.best_match(cards)}')
    print(f'Best Completion: {combos.best_completion(cards, available_cards)}')
    print("")
```

Comment: I am afraid that most reviewers do not have the first idea what the game is about. A short intro would be very helpful.

Comment: @vnp Added a more detailed description, I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overall it's pretty sane. I'll call out an assorted laundry list of suggestions -

`_card_id_generator` is really just an `itertools.count`, and you don't even care about the iterator itself, just its `__next__`; so:

```py
import itertools

"""
This generator function yields a unique card ID each time it's invoked. This is to ensure that the distinct
identity of each card is maintained in set operations when there are multiple copies of the same card in
a user-defined game variant.
"""
_get_card_id = itertools.count().__next__


@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Card:
    """
    Represents a playing card with a color, value, and unique ID.
    """
    id: int = field(default_factory=_get_card_id)
```

An alternative way of writing the above would be making a nested function that increments and returns a non-local, but I don't consider that a particularly better idea.

You're missing various typehints. `__lt__(self, other: 'Card') -> bool` for one. `__init__` always returns `-> None`. `_select_highest_cards_to_add` needs typehints. I strongly recommend running mypy; when I was refactoring it caught a bunch of real issues.

You use `Sequence` in various places for your card hand, but since the order of the hand does not matter, you should generalise to `Collection`.

`__add__` is typically assumed to return a new instance of `Card` and not a bare integer. This reveals a design problem in your API: how do you easily get the `Card` with a given value? You can't use your current constructor because it will assign a new monotonic ID, which doesn't represent reality. Probably you should scrap the ID altogether, which would make constructing equivalent `Card` instances easy. At the same time you can simplify from `@dataclass` to `NamedTuple`; this will allow set and sort operations and is naturally immutable.

You don't even use `__add__` it seems. What you *would* use is `__sub__` between two card values, which would return an `int`.

You use `list` in a lot of places where you should be using `tuple`, as the latter is immutable. In some cases `list` is inescapable like when you incrementally build lists on the inside of a default dictionary.

I don't find it helpful that `Combo` is a `Protocol`. Protocols are most useful in declaring callables with well-defined parameter names and types, etc. Here, `Combo` is basically an abstract class from which your other combinations should inherit. You can use `abc` if you want, but usually I just declare abstract methods as throwing `NotImplementedError`.

This is not a good iteration model:

```py
        while highest_value - lowest_value >= min_value_spread:
            highest_value -= 1
```

Instead you should be running through a `range`.

`_generate_values_to_test` can simply yield integer `range`s rather than lists.

`Args` documentation in `HelperStepSize` is in the incorrect place; it should be documented on the constructor.

`best_completion` may be rewritten as a generator on which you call `next(best_completion, [])`.

`_cards_have_correct_step_size` may be rewritten as a call to `all()` on a generator.

The dictionary `update` call in `_select_one_card_per_value` may be rewritten as the `|` union of two dictionary comprehensions; or one dictionary comprehension of the form

```py
return {
    card.value: card
    for card in chain(available_cards, cards_to_complete)
}
```

`_select_cards_to_test` may be rewritten as a call to `filter` on a generator (not a list comprehension).

`best_completion` may be rewritten so that `max` is called on a generator and not an incrementally-constructed list.

This:

`all(card in cards_to_test for card in cards_to_complete) and self.is_match(cards_to_test)`

is effectively just a subset containment predicate:

`set(cards_to_complete) <= set(cards_to_test)`

`_eq_attr` is a smell. There's no way to make that code type-safe. This should be re-worked so that there are no arbitrary attributes. The easy way is to accept a transformation callable that produces a member from a class instance, and uses the member type as a `Generic` type variable.

`_prepare_cards_to_test` uses expression `cards_by_attr[self._eq_attr(card)]` that should be assigned to a temporary variable for reuse.

This loop:

```
        for cards_to_test in cards_by_attr.values():
            yield cards_to_test
```

should not exist; simply `return cards_by_attr.values()`.

`cards_to_test = [*cards_to_complete, *cards_to_add]`, assuming that both variables are lists, can just use `+` concatenation instead of unpack-and-list-literal.

`print("")` is just `print()`.

Your `__repr__` definitions are not used, so I would just delete them.

Convert your rule demonstration code into unit tests. I did this to verify that my refactoring produces output the same as that of the original code.

### Suggested

Covering most of the above,

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from collections.abc import Iterable, Iterator
from itertools import chain
from typing import NamedTuple, Collection, TypeVar, Generic, Callable, DefaultDict


class Card(NamedTuple):
    """
    Represents a playing card with a color and value
    """
    color: str
    value: int

    def __lt__(self, other: 'Card') -> bool:
        return self.value < other.value

    def __add__(self, diff: int) -> 'Card':
        return Card(color=self.color, value=self.value + diff)

    def __sub__(self, other: 'Card') -> int:
        return self.value - other.value

    # Convenience methods for helper transformation
    def get_color(self) -> str: return self.color
    def get_value(self) -> int: return self.value


class Combo:
    name: str
    rank: int
    n_cards_complete_combo: int

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        raise NotImplementedError()

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class HelperStepSize:
    """
    A helper class to handle operations related to the step size in a combo.
    """

    def __init__(self, n_cards_complete_combo: int, step_size: int) -> None:
        """
        Args:
            n_cards_complete_combo: The number of cards required to complete the combo. Must be larger than 0.
            step_size: The required step size of the values of the cards that make up the combo. Must be larger than 0.
        """
        self._n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._step_size = step_size

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the given cards match the combo criteria. 'cards' may be an empty Collection.
        """
        return len(cards) == self._n_cards_complete_combo and self._cards_have_correct_step_size(cards)

    def all_completions(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> Iterator[tuple[Card, ...]]:
        card_samples = self._select_one_card_per_value(cards_to_complete, available_cards)
        highest_value = max(card_samples.keys(), default=0)
        lowest_value = min(card_samples.keys(), default=0)

        for values_to_test in self._generate_values_to_test(highest_value, lowest_value):
            cards_to_test = tuple(self._select_cards_to_test(card_samples, values_to_test))
            if self._are_cards_to_test_valid(cards_to_test, cards_to_complete):
                yield cards_to_test

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards using the available cards. Both 'cards_to_complete' and
        'available_cards' may be an empty Collection. If no valid completion is found, returns an empty tuple.
        """
        return next(self.all_completions(cards_to_complete, available_cards), ())

    @staticmethod
    def _hand_steps(hand: Collection[Card]) -> Iterator[int]:
        card_seq = sorted(hand)
        for this_card, next_card in zip(card_seq[:-1], card_seq[1:]):
            yield next_card - this_card

    def _cards_have_correct_step_size(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the sorted values of 'cards' all have a step size that equals 'self._step_size'.
        """
        return all(step == self._step_size for step in self._hand_steps(cards))

    @staticmethod
    def _select_one_card_per_value(
        cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> dict[int, Card]:
        """
        Selects one card per value from the given 'cards_to_complete' and 'available_cards'. Gives priority to
        cards from 'cards_to_complete' if both 'cards_to_complete' and 'available_cards' contain a valid sample.
        """
        return {
            card.value: card
            for card in chain(available_cards, cards_to_complete)
        }

    def _generate_values_to_test(
        self, highest_value: int, lowest_value: int,
    ) -> Iterator[range]:
        """
        Returns Collections of values in descending order, each containing 'self._n_cards_complete_combo' values, and
        all values having a step size equal to 'self._step_size'. The highest possible value of a sequence is
        'highest_value', and the lowest possible value is 'lowest_value'.

        For example, when highest_value=8, lowest_value=2, self._step_size=2 and self._n_cards_complete_combo=3,
        this will yield: [8, 6, 4], [7, 5, 3], [6, 4, 2].
        """
        min_value_spread = self._step_size * (self._n_cards_complete_combo - 1)
        for upper_value in range(highest_value, lowest_value + min_value_spread - 1, -1):
            valid_range = range(upper_value, lowest_value - 1, -self._step_size)
            yield valid_range[:self._n_cards_complete_combo]

    @staticmethod
    def _select_cards_to_test(
        card_samples: dict[int, Card], values_to_test: Iterable[int],
    ) -> Iterator[Card]:
        """
        Selects cards from the 'card_samples' dictionary based on the values in 'values_to_test'.
        """
        for value in values_to_test:
            card = card_samples.get(value)
            if card is not None:
                yield card

    def _are_cards_to_test_valid(
        self, cards_to_test: Collection[Card], cards_to_complete: Collection[Card],
    ) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the selected cards to test are valid: all cards in 'cards_to_complete' must appear in 'cards_to_test',
        and 'cards_to_test' must pass the criteria of 'self.is_match'.
        """
        return set(cards_to_complete) <= set(cards_to_test) and self.is_match(cards_to_test)


EqualAttr = TypeVar('EqualAttr')


class HelperEqualAttribute(Generic[EqualAttr]):
    """
    A helper class to handle operations related to equal attributes in a combo.
    """

    def __init__(
        self,
        n_cards_complete_combo: int,
        attr_transform: Callable[[Card], EqualAttr],
    ) -> None:
        """
        Args:
            n_cards_complete_combo: The number of cards required to complete the combo. Must be larger than 0.
        """
        self._n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._eq_attr = attr_transform

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the given cards match the combo criteria. 'cards' may be an empty Collection.
        """
        return len(cards) == self._n_cards_complete_combo and self._cards_have_eq_attr(cards)

    def _all_completions(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> Iterator[tuple[Card, ...]]:
        for cards_to_test in self._prepare_cards_to_test(cards_to_complete, available_cards):
            if self._are_cards_to_test_valid(cards_to_test, cards_to_complete):
                yield tuple(cards_to_test)

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards using the available cards. Both 'cards_to_complete' and
        'available_cards' may be an empty Collection. If no valid completion is found, returns an empty list.
        """
        return max(self._all_completions(cards_to_complete, available_cards), default=())

    def _cards_have_eq_attr(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        """Checks if 'self._attr_to_test' matches for all cards."""
        return len({self._eq_attr(card) for card in cards}) == 1

    def _prepare_cards_to_test(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection,
    ) -> Collection[list[Card]]:
        """Organizes cards for testing, grouping them by attribute value.

        - If the number of cards required to complete the combo is less than or equal to `self._n_cards_complete_combo`,
          all cards from `cards_to_complete` are included.
        - If additional cards are needed to meet `self._n_cards_complete_combo`, the method adds the highest-valued
          cards from `available_cards`.
        """
        ac_by_value = sorted(available_cards, reverse=True)
        cards_by_attr: DefaultDict[EqualAttr, list[Card]] = defaultdict(list)

        for card in chain(cards_to_complete, ac_by_value):
            cards_for_attr = cards_by_attr[self._eq_attr(card)]
            if len(cards_for_attr) < self._n_cards_complete_combo:
                cards_for_attr.append(card)

        return cards_by_attr.values()

    def _are_cards_to_test_valid(
        self, cards_to_test: Collection[Card], cards_to_complete: Collection[Card],
    ) -> bool:
        """
        Checks if the selected cards to test are valid: all cards in 'cards_to_complete' must appear in 'cards_to_test',
        and 'cards_to_test' must pass the criteria in 'self.is_match'.
        """
        return all(
            card in cards_to_test for card in cards_to_complete
        ) and self.is_match(cards_to_test)


class ComboAnyCards(Combo):
    """
    All cards allowed.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        return len(cards) == self.n_cards_complete_combo

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        cards_to_add = self._select_highest_cards_to_add(cards_to_complete, available_cards)
        cards_to_test = tuple(cards_to_complete) + tuple(cards_to_add)
        return cards_to_test if self.is_match(cards_to_test) else ()

    def _select_highest_cards_to_add(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> list[Card]:
        n_cards_to_add = self.n_cards_complete_combo - len(cards_to_complete)
        return sorted(available_cards, reverse=True)[:n_cards_to_add]


class ComboStepSizeOne(Combo):
    """
    Cards must have consecutive values.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_step_size = HelperStepSize(self.n_cards_complete_combo, step_size=1)

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_step_size.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        return self._helper_step_size.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)


class ComboEqualColors(Combo):
    """
    Cards must have equal colors.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_colors = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, Card.get_color)

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)


class ComboEqualValues(Combo):
    """
    Cards must have equal values.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_values = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, Card.get_value)

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_values.is_match(cards)

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        return self._helper_equal_values.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)


class ComboEqualColorsStepSizeOne(Combo):
    """
    Cards must have both equal colors and consecutive values.
    """

    def __init__(self, name: str, rank: int, n_cards_complete_combo: int) -> None:
        self.name = name
        self.rank = rank
        self.n_cards_complete_combo = n_cards_complete_combo
        self._helper_equal_colors = HelperEqualAttribute(self.n_cards_complete_combo, Card.get_color)
        self._helper_step_size = HelperStepSize(self.n_cards_complete_combo, step_size=1)

    def is_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> bool:
        return self._helper_equal_colors.is_match(cards) and self._helper_step_size.is_match(cards)

    def _all_completions(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> Iterator[tuple[Card, ...]]:
        for available_cards_to_test in self._prepare_available_cards_to_test(available_cards):
            completion = self._helper_step_size.best_completion(cards_to_complete,
                                                                available_cards_to_test)
            if self.is_match(completion):
                yield completion

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Card, ...]:
        return max(self._all_completions(cards_to_complete, available_cards), default=())

    @staticmethod
    def _prepare_available_cards_to_test(available_cards: Collection[Card]) -> Iterator[list[Card]]:
        """
        Prepares available cards for testing by grouping them by color.
        """
        cards_by_color = defaultdict(list)
        for card in available_cards:
            cards_by_color[card.color].append(card)

        for available_cards_to_test in cards_by_color.values():
            yield available_cards_to_test


class ActiveCombos:
    def __init__(self, active_combos: Iterable[Combo]) -> None:
        self.active_combos: list[Combo] = sorted(active_combos, key=lambda combo: combo.rank)

    def best_match(self, cards: Collection[Card]) -> Combo | None:
        """
        Matches 'cards' with the best possible combo type in 'active_combos'.
        """
        for combo in self.active_combos:
            if combo.is_match(cards):
                return combo
        return None

    def best_completion(
        self, cards_to_complete: Collection[Card], available_cards: Collection[Card],
    ) -> tuple[Combo | None, tuple[Card, ...]]:
        """
        Finds the best completion for the given cards to complete a combo among the active combos.
        """
        for combo in self.active_combos:
            completion = combo.best_completion(cards_to_complete, available_cards)
            if completion:
                return combo, completion
        return None, ()


class GameSettings(NamedTuple):
    card_colors: tuple[str, ...]
    card_values: tuple[int, ...] | range
    hand_size: int
    n_targets: int
    target_name: str
    max_n_cards_complete_combo: int
    active_combos: tuple[Combo, ...]


SCHOTTEN_TOTTEN = GameSettings(
    card_colors=('red', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow', 'brown', 'purple'),
    card_values=range(1, 10),
    hand_size=6,
    n_targets=9,
    target_name='stone',
    max_n_cards_complete_combo=3,
    active_combos=(
        ComboEqualColorsStepSizeOne(name='COLOR-RUN', rank=1, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboEqualValues(name='THREE OF A KIND', rank=2, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboEqualColors(name='COLOR', rank=3, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboStepSizeOne(name='RUN', rank=4, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
        ComboAnyCards(name='SUM', rank=5, n_cards_complete_combo=3),
    ),
)


def test() -> None:
    combos = ActiveCombos(SCHOTTEN_TOTTEN.active_combos)
    available_cards = (Card('green', 4), Card('blue', 5), Card('red', 5), Card('green', 3))

    cards_to_test: tuple[Card, ...] = Card('blue', 1), Card('blue', 3), Card('blue', 2)
    match = combos.best_match(cards_to_test)
    assert match.name == 'COLOR-RUN'
    assert match.rank == 1
    assert match.n_cards_complete_combo == 3
    combo, cards = combos.best_completion(cards_to_test, available_cards)
    assert combo is match
    assert cards == (Card('blue', 3), Card('blue', 2), Card('blue', 1))

    cards_to_test = Card('blue', 3), Card('red', 2)
    assert combos.best_match(cards_to_test) is None
    combo, cards = combos.best_completion(cards_to_test, available_cards)
    assert combo.name == 'RUN'
    assert combo.rank == 4
    assert combo.n_cards_complete_combo == 3
    assert cards == (Card('green', 4), Card('blue', 3), Card('red', 2))

    cards_to_test = Card('green', 5),
    assert combos.best_match(cards_to_test) is None
    combo, cards = combos.best_completion(cards_to_test, available_cards)
    assert combo.name == 'COLOR-RUN'
    assert combo.rank == 1
    assert combo.n_cards_complete_combo == 3
    assert cards == (Card('green', 5), Card('green', 4), Card('green', 3))

    cards_to_test = ()
    assert combos.best_match(cards_to_test) is None
    combo, cards = combos.best_completion(cards_to_test, available_cards)
    assert combo.name == 'RUN'
    assert combo.rank == 4
    assert combo.n_cards_complete_combo == 3
    assert cards == (Card('red', 5), Card('green', 4), Card('green', 3))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: Thank you for your helpful code review! I have a few questions:

- Card: I want to be able to use multiple copies of the same card when applying rule variants (for example, have three yellow cards, all with value 2). But I don't want to worry about set operations kicking out cards with the same attributes, because they are not the same card in the context of the game. Is there a way to do this without using an ID?

Comment: Tricky. Either include an ID (but ask for it explicitly as part of card construction), or maybe wrap the card in a card instance object that has an ID.

Comment: I know this isn't in the final review, but wouldn't the `itertools.count().__next__` be a bit more pythonic as a `partial`? Something like `_get_card_id = partial(next, itertools.count())`

Comment: Debatable. I expect `__next__` to have better performance, not that it matters. It's also simpler in that it's already a bound function.